# How to count how many homomorphisms from a (finite) cyclic group to another?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

I know that to define a homomorphism between cyclic groups, we only need to determine where the generator goes to. But any smart general idea to determine which choice can send zero to zero?

Comment: If $f(1)\cdot m = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$, then $f$ can be extended to a homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}_m\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_n$. Using this fact, you can count the number of homomorphisms, i.e. the number of homomorphisms is the cardinality of the set $\{x\in\mathbb{Z}_n\mid x\cdot m=0\}$.